# Confusing error message in data explorer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer, error-message

Try following:

1. go to query http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/734
2. enter <kbd>abc</kbd> as `UserId`
3. run query
4. you'll get this error message: `Error: Invalid column name 'abc'.`

Error message should say something like "got a string for UserId when expecting a number" or "can't convert 'abc' to an integer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way we can improve on this is to introduce strongly typed params, at the moment they are a directly injected with a text substitution.

If we knew they were supposed to be ints then we could do something nicer, but that would make the metadata format for params more verbose. Eg `##UserId##:int`. I guess we could assume any param ending with `Id` should be a number.

Comment: There are only limited number of parameter types. You could try them all out with normal sql parameter binding. Jeff Atwood had a meta post ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51395/can-we-become-our-own-northwind-for-teaching-sql-databases ) about possible educational aspects of Data Explorer. I think that an example of sql injection should not be one of them ;)

Comment: @Juha, we are allowing people to execute arbitrary SQL here, sql injection really is not a concern, inject away the connection to the db is running under a read-only user

Answer (score 2):

You get your expected error when you quote your text  (`'abc'`):

> **Error:** Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'abc' to data type int.

The token is just replaced, so the query is

```
...
and owneruserid = abc
...
```

Since `abc` is not quoted, it is considered to be a column name.

Comment: So this has built-in sql injection vulnerability? But that doesn't probably matter, since you can directly do any queries you like.

Comment: @Juha Syrjälä: Yes, sort of. You can execute this query for example: `##x##` and enter `Select * From posts` as value for `x`. But as you say, you can edit the query anyway so this doesn't make a difference.

Comment: re vulnerability, try "drop table Posts​" or "delete from Posts" or "update Posts set Score = 0"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox