# So data-explorer questions go here?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I ask questions about data explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107137/where-do-i-ask-questions-about-data-explorer)

I recently noticed Jeff Atwood tagging some Data Explorer questions as [status-*]. So is MSO the new home of Data Explorer related questions? It seems like that would've gone on https://stackapps.com/ Does this mean that Data Explorer is officially part of the Stack Overflow family now and not just a 3rd party extension?

Comment: And I have now created [Data Explorer Discussions](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/495) in chat too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jeff [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51395#comment-120566)

> you can ask those questions here, just
>   tag them [data-explorer]

Answer (score 2):

See halfway through [this Atwood post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51395/can-we-become-our-own-northwind-for-teaching-sql-databases). So yes, it's becoming officially part of the Stack Overflow Trilogy.