# Where do I ask questions about data explorer?

Tags: discussion, meta, data-explorer

The tag wiki for [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) says:

> The Data Explorer, located at data.stackexchange.com, allows you to
> create and run queries against copies of the databases of popular
> StackExchange sites to investigate trends or satisfy your curiosity.
>
> For questions about the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq),
> [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com)

So there's a link to the FAQ, but it seems to imply that `data.stackexchange.com` is the place to *ask* questions about Data Explorer (I can't find any questions about DE there, though). By contrast, [Where can you discuss or ask for comments on a data explorer query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91086/where-can-you-discuss-or-ask-for-comments-on-a-data-explorer-query) says questions are asked here. Which one is it?

Comment: yes here ... what's up ?

Comment: @waffles: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107154/explore-what-tags-are-associated-with-questions-with-tag1-but-not-tag2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You ask them here. I think the tag wiki meant "This tag is for questions about the Data Explorer, located at data.stackexchange.com", but it was confusing so I edited it to just include the first part.