# Data Explorer query results: align columns with numerical data to right

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, design, data-explorer

If column type in Data Explorer's query is numerical, it should be right aligned. Looks nicer that way.

Like this:

```
   123
     0
321123
  1231
 99999
```

Not like this (current situation):

```
123
0
321123
1231
99999
```

Comment: More? Someone wants Mortarboard today. ;)

Comment: Well, somebody did want separate posts http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51395/can-we-become-our-own-northwind-for-teaching-sql-databases/51486#51486 ;)

Comment: please keep'em coming :)

Comment: This is actually completed just waiting for an admin to mark it so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature request is completed.