# StackOverflow OData End Point Doesn't Support JSONP

Tags: support, data-explorer

First of all please excuse me for opening new thread, however, the other one is few years old.

I was wondering whether https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom supports JSONP at all. Adding $callback and $filter to the query string results in server-side error. On the other hand, it is not possible to add Accept: "application/json" header for JSONP requests.
Finally I tried accessing the service with "normal" (non JSONP) request, hoping that there is CORS however, no avail.

All in all it is not possible to access the feed through JavaScript unless I am missing something super obvious. In short, is there any way to consume the service from JavaScript?

Comment: And "the other one" is which question precisely?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not trying to use the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) instead? The odata endpoint on Data Explorer exists, but is not particularly well-maintained because the API provides more current data and more advanced functionality anyway.

Comment: Yes, I had the intention to use the service for testing purposes. Thanks for clarification, I will find another public service that fits my needs.

Answer (score 6):

With rev. 2015.4.22.34 the [odata endpoints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247931/hide-the-broken-odata-link-in-data-explorer/254120#254120) got hidden because they were dysfunctional for a long time.

Your best option is the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) as indicated by Tim. Alternatively you could use one of the [methods I described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250977/how-do-i-automate-the-data-explorer-download/250990#250990) to get the data you need.