# odata access from data.stackexchange.com down

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, data-explorer

The OData endpoint provided at data.stackexchange.com has been down for the last few days. I have searched for information about the outage, but I can't find any reason or explanation. Can someone shed some light on the situation?

To be specific, every query I make gives the result "Page not found", with a picture of Edgar Codd. Example:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Users

Comment: Data Explorer recently moved, and I suspect that rewrite required for the OData endpoint to work isn't operating correctly. Out of curiosity, what is your use case for the OData endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. So I hope it will come back up? My use case is  looking up stackexchange users by different criteria, usually email hash. As far as I can see, I can't do this with the stackexchange API.

Answer (score 3):

So there were many reasons this was broken after a move across the country:

1. The connection string was wrong (SEDE assume it ends in `;`, it doesn't anymore)
2. Our IIS config didn't allow HTTP activation (it does not, but *only* for this)
3. Cassini locally doesn't even do URL rewrite (VS 2010 project, ick)

It's is fixed for now.  However, *if it breaks again* due to another move or such we likely will not fix it.  Supporting OData requires a lot of configuration and features in our environment that are otherwise not needed, it eats a lot of time (and somtimes resources) that are just really hard to justify given the usage it gets.

Comment: Yeah, it would be really nice just to cut it out of the project completely...always wondered what people are still using it for.

Comment: It seems to be broken now. It might be best to remove the links if you guys aren't going to maintain it so it doesn't get our hopes up. :)