# Odata feeds are down

Tags: bug, data-explorer

Seems to be lots of reports for this, but none recently it seems.

So, odata feeds are down, i emailed about this but was told to report it here.

https://data.stackexchange.com/

Click any of the sites... ie: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries
and you will see that there is a link to odata, but when you click it you get the page not found page:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom

Answer (score 5):

I fear that's the end of OData, [quoting Nick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192382/152859):

> However, if it breaks again due to another move or such **we likely will not fix it**. Supporting OData requires a lot of configuration and features in our environment that are otherwise not needed, it eats a lot of time (and somtimes resources) that are just really hard to justify given the usage it gets.

So, unless I'm proven wrong, that's my base assumption.

Comment: In that case we should commit a change on the github repo to remove the links...

Comment: @rene that's Tim's (Stone) job! ;)

Comment: He would pull...