# How do I automate the data explorer download?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

How do I automate the data explorer download? Has anybody done that? I want to build an app which would use this data. I want this data to be updated automatically. Is there an JDBC connection or an API call available which I can run daily.

Comment: From what I recall, they're only updated weekly, so a daily download would be overkill.

Comment: If you need data more current than the weekly data dump, you should presumably use [the Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8):

If you are referring to [The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) there used to be an [option for an odata](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230749/158100) connection but that got switched off some time ago due to stabillity/configuration issues. It is not definitely cancelled but it isn't working at the moment as well.

If you are interested in the result of one or more queries you created on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) you can use the [Download CSV](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/csv/7672) link for each query. Scripting that with [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) is not hard.

[image]

The databases under SEDE are refreshed weekly, in the weekend. The maxium number of rows returned in SEDE is 50,000 (with some [tricks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237251/158100) you might [get more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234774/158100))

If you are looking to get all data in your own database based on the [The Internet Archive Stack Exchange Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) you can use the scripts from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats). Notice this data is updated quarterly-ish.

To have near-live access to questions, answers, comments, users and sites among other data you might explore the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) with its support site [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). Do notice that you are allowed only a certain amount of calls per day and you are throttled if you make to many calls per minute. For the current details check the [rate limits](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

Comment: I want to have the result of [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1332541) query: `DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT 
  c.Score, 
  c.Id as [Comment Link],
  p.Id as [Post Link],
  c.Text,
  c.CreationDate,
  c.UserId as [User Link]
FROM 
  Comments c, Posts p
WHERE
  p.Id = c.PostId AND
  c.UserId = @UserId
ORDER BY
  c.Score DESC` on my website on github pages (no server, only js).The option with csv does not work because I am serverless.Just creating an api link seems impossible because of 2 tables in use(comments and posts).

Comment: @user3123159 this will work `https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-users#order=desc&sort=votes&ids=811&filter=!)Q2A3(brA9BlriV-A2Kh)6X3&site=stackoverflow&run=true` but if you want the question title, you have to do an extra call per comment to get the title of the posts from the posts endpoint `https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=243778&filter=!9_bDDt835&site=stackoverflow&run=true` that can all be done client side with a bit of javascript run in the browser